# Access data from other model in a ListView

Tags: django, django-views

Good morning,

how can I access data from another model in my ListView ?

Right now I have a model called Project and I I am using ListView in order to render a a list of all current projects.

My Project is linked to another models call Team that has multiple Members and each members has an attribute called Response_set. 
I would like that in my HTML template if Response_set is not empty for each member put a Green Mark else put a red mark.

The thing is I do not know and do not find the answer on how to loop through my list within the view;

```
 class HRIndex(generic.ListView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "HR_index.html"
    model = Project
    ordering = ['-created_at']


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        context = super(HRIndex,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        status_dict = {}
        for project in object_list:
            proj_team_id = project.team_id
            proj_memb = proj_team_id.members.all()
            open_close = 1
            for memb in proj_memb:
                if not list(memb.response_set.all()):
                    status = False
                else:
                    status = True
                open_close = open_close*status
            status_dict.update({project.id:open_close})

        context['status_dict'] = status_dict
        return context
```

I tried using object_list like in the template but it not working

How can I loop through my list in my view ? 
Thx you

Comment: could you try writing a model method?